# how is jtwitter OAuth switching?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, jtwitter

Here is my code:

```
 import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
    import winterwell.jtwitter.*;
    import java.util.List;


public class twitterbagla {

    private static final String username="blabla";
    private static final String password="xx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twitter twitter=new Twitter (username,password);
        System.out.println(twitter.getStatus("hah"));
        //System.out.println(twitter.getFollowers());

        twitter.setStatus("hello world something");
        List<User> followers=twitter.getFollowers();
        for(User user : followers){
            System.out.println(user.getName());

        }


    }

}
```

and here is console

> It's amazing to me that the best things in life are steps forward that come with negative assumptions.
>   Exception in thread "main" winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$UpdateToOAuth: You need to switch to OAuth. Twitter no longer support basic authentication.
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:369)
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.post2(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:303)
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.post(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:272)
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2593)
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2519)
>       at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.setStatus(Twitter.java:2291)
>       at twitterbagla.main(twitterbagla.java:16)

Comment: What exactly is unclear about that error? It's obviously that you should switch to OAuth..

Comment: I know but I am new on this, how can I switch it? can you show this with coding?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#java You can find some libraries here..

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation at http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php

You want to create an OAuthSignpostClient. There's then an authorisation step with Twitter (you can store the resulting tokens to reuse later).

Then use new `Twitter(name, oauthClient)` to create your Twitter instance.